# Converting SQL join query to django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, join

I am new to django models and trying to convert legacy MySQL queries to django models. I have two tables tb1 and tb2. I want to join the two and use both of their fields to get results.

```
class Tb2(models.Model):
   tb2_id = models.ForeignKey('Tb1', models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
   profile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   version = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Tb1(models.Model):
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   job_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

""" SELECT s.*, IF(count(distinct p.version)<=1, TRUE, FALSE) is_profile_same,
       MAX(p.version) ver,
       FROM tb1 s
       LEFT JOIN tb2 p ON p.tb2_id=s.id
       WHERE s.id in ('10','9') group by s.id  """

Tb1.tb1.filter().select_related('Tb2').annotate(join_profiles=Count('id'))
```

I have left joined the two tables on the ids. I am not sure how to add the if and max conditions using the fields of the tb2. Every time i try to use the fields it gives me FieldError.

Can someone help?

Comment: Since `tb2_id` is a `ForeignKey` to `Tb1` and a primary key as well, there can never be two `tb2`s (or more for a given `tb1`). So the `IF COUNT(...)` is useless here.

Comment: thanks @WillemVanOnsem i'll remove the if count. however how can i add max filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something a bit "odd" with your models. The `ForeignKey` from `Tb2` to `Tb1` is a `primary_key=True` as well. This thus means that this `ForeignKey` is unique, and therefore there can only be (at most) one `Tb2` that links to a `Tb1`. This thus means that the `COUNT(DISTINCT p.version)` will always be at most one.

You can however retrieve the maximum of the given version with:

```
Tb1.objects.filter(
    pk__in=[10, 9]
).annotate(
    ver=Max('tb2__version')
)
```

If there is *no* related `Tb2` instance, it will pass `None` to the `ver` attribute.

Comment: Error : Cannot resolve keyword 'tb2' into field. It picks up the field names og Tb1 only

Comment: @RNA: did you by any chance provided a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey`? Or named your `Tb2` differently?